# how to add a new "key-value" pair for existing child in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've connected my android app to firebase and enabled email and password authentication. My current database status is like :

[image: current structure of database]

Now I want to add an extra field (key:"number")for all users i have so that my final database looks like:

[image: final structure of database]

so please tell me how can I do this ?

One more important thing is I wrote code such that I first authenticate them, if their registration is succesfull then I take user to new Activity where they will enter this "key" after collecting the key I should add this to user node as shown in the second picture.

So please tell me how to do this?

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write a value in the Firebase Realtime Database, you must know the complete path to that value. So in your case that means that you first have to load all data from the database, to be able to determine the dynamic keys (`C76w3...`, `FjsZ...`, etc).

Something like this:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            snapshot.getRef().child("key").setValue("hisoka");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this Iam getting an error saying "cannot find reference "  and the suggestion provided by ide is "Rename reference".  Please help

Comment: On what specific line/symbol of the code I gave do you get that message?

Comment: On this line: snapshot.child("key").setValue("hisoka");

Comment: Ah yeah, I see it. There needs to be a `getRef()` in there, since a `DataSnapshot` doesn't have a `setValue()` method. Note that studying the reference documentation is quite handy in cases like this.